# Is there a way to conduct one tailed t-test using add_p or add_difference function in tbl_summary?

Tags: r, t-test, gtsummary

I wanted to include the results of one-tailed t-test using gtsummary. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please provide code an example of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to `t.test()` via the `add_p(test.args=)` argument. In your case, you'll want to pass the `t.test(alternative = "less")` (or `"greater"`) argument. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, marker, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p(
    all_continuous() ~ "t.test",
    test.args = all_tests("t.test") ~ list(alternative = "less")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>